# Bootstrap align an item to left of a button

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to align

```
<div class="pull-right inside site-description ">
     {% include "menu/menu-lang.html" %}
</div>
```

to left of

```
 <a class="btn red_button" href="{% url 'user-login' %}">{% trans 'Log in' %}</a>
```

How will i do it?

Comment: is this works?
 <a class="btn pull-right red_button" href="{% url 'user-login' %}">{% trans 'Log in' %}</a>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you are putting the code before the `<a href...` and change `pull-right` to `pull-left`:

```
<div class="pull-left inside site-description ">
   {% include "menu/menu-lang.html" %}
</div>
```

Also adding the class `pull-right` to the `<a href...` might be effective. Ultimately, your code should look this way:

```
<div class="pull-left inside site-description ">
   {% include "menu/menu-lang.html" %}
</div>
<a class="btn red_button pull-right" href="{% url 'user-login' %}">{% trans 'Log in' %}</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

check following link, where i have done some modification, to make the div left of your anchor tag:

http://www.bootply.com/Wx4mypccsH

Also, you can rearrange your html structure.